# Using a callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, youtube

**Bug reproduction steps:**

- Open http://jaminweb.com/YoutubePlaylist.html
- Enter `sMqNFAU0tOw` (or any other Youtube video ID) into the playlist
- Click **Play Videos!**
- JavaScript console should say something like Uncaught `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

**Attempt at diagnosing the problem:**

The **Play Videos!** button calls the following function

```
        this.playAll = function()
        {
            var vidtexts = document.getElementsByClassName('vidtxt');
            for (var i = 0, j = vidtexts.length; i < j; ++i)
            {
               var thisid = vidtexts[i].value;
               if (thisid.length > 0)
               {
                   var thisurl = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + thisid + "?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3";                    
                    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
                    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };

                    swfobject.embedSWF(thisurl, "playerdiv", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts, this.playVid);

               }
            }
        }
```

which in turn calls the following function

```
        this.playVid = function(e)
        {
            /* Callback function for swfobject.embedSWF(...), to play the video
               if the flash player was loaded successfully. */
            if (e.success)
            {
                var ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
                ytplayer.playVideo();
                while (ytplayer.getPlayerState() == 1) {;} // need to change this sometime lol
            }
        }
```

The console error is pointing to the line

```
ytplayer.playVideo();
```

So the problem is that the object `ytplayer` has not been instantiated at the time that `playVideo()` is called. I don't understand why that is, because when I used the function

```
                    swfobject.embedSWF(thisurl, "playerdiv", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts, this.playVid);
```

I included as an optional parameter the callback function `this.playVid` which I wrote to call `ytplayer.playVideo();` only if a `swf` object with id `myytplayer` has been created.

**Relevant documentation:**

https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.embedSWF%28swfUrlStr,_replaceElemIdStr,_widthStr,_height

Answer (score 0):

This works in chrome. And in IE 10.

```
    VideoPlayer = function () {
        this.addVideo = function () {
            var newVidElement = document.createElement("div");
            newVidElement.className = "videl";
            newVidElement.innerHTML = "<p><textarea class='vidtxt'></textarea><img class='rembtn' src='remicon.png' width=20 height=20></img></p>";
            document.getElementById("vidplaydiv").appendChild(newVidElement);
        }
        this.playAll = function () {
            var vidtexts = document.getElementsByClassName('vidtxt');
            for (var i = 0, j = vidtexts.length; i < j; ++i) {
                var thisid = vidtexts[i].value;
                if (thisid.length > 0) {
                    var thisurl = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + thisid + "?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3";
                    var atts = {
                        id: "myytplayer"
                    };
                    var params = {
                        allowScriptAccess: "always"
                    };

                    swfobject.embedSWF(thisurl, "playerdiv", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts, this.playVid);

                }
            }
        }
        this.playVid = function (e) {
            /* Callback function for swfobject.embedSWF(...), to play the video
               if the flash player was loaded successfully. */
            if (e.success) {
                var ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
                ytplayer.playVideo();
                while (ytplayer.getPlayerState() == 1) {;
                } // need to change this
            }
        }
    }
```